# Decoding packet capture files .cap in java

Tags: pcap

I have a packet capture file .cap .It is encoded with g.722.How do i convert it to a playable format eg.wav form.

Comment: don't know how to do it in java but there's a tool that'll do it - can't find source http://softwaretopic.informer.com/pcap-to-wav/

Comment: apparently these tools are not working for that.Do you have an idea of how to decode the g.722 codec to create an rtp dump.